# Channel Form - Conditionally Show Fields

Tags: channel-form

Basically have a form to submit to a channel but need to show some extra fields depending on whether user clicks yes/no on a radio button. If yes then the hidden custom fields should appear.

Has anyone done this with Channel Form in EE 2.8.1 ? Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it can probably be done with jQuery, in which some script is loaded so that when a user clicks the radio button some hidden divs show up with the extra fields you want.  Just make sure the hidden divs are nested within the channel:form tags.

I've not tested this, but this might get you going in the right direction with showing hidden divs on radio button selection with jQuery:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940963/jquery-show-and-hide-divs-based-on-radio-button-click